# How to efficiently grow large data in R

Tags: r, optimization

The product of one simulation is a large data.frame, with fixed columns and rows. I ran several hundreds of simulations, with each result stored in a separate RData file (for efficient reading).

Now I want to gather all those files together and create statistics for each field of this `data.frame` into the "cells" structure which is basically a list of vectors with . This is how I do it:

```
#colscount, rowscount - number of columns and rows from each simulation
#simcount - number of simulation.
#colnames - names of columns of simulation's data frame.
#simfilenames - vector with filenames with each simulation 

cells<-as.list(rep(NA, colscount))
for(i in 1:colscount)
{
  cells[[i]]<-as.list(rep(NA,rowscount)) 
  for(j in 1:rows)
  {
    cells[[i]][[j]]<-rep(NA,simcount)
  }
}
names(cells)<-colnames

addcells<-function(simnr)
# This function reads and appends simdata to "simnr" position in each cell in the "cells" structure
{
  simdata<readRDS(simfilenames[[simnr]])
  for(i in 1:colscount)
  {
    for(j in 1:rowscount)
    {
      if (!is.na(simdata[j,i]))
      {
        cells[[i]][[j]][simnr]<-simdata[j,i]
      }
    }
  }
}
library(plyr)
a_ply(1:simcount,1,addcells)
```

The problem is, that this the

```
> system.time(dane<-readRDS(path.cat(args$rdatapath,pliki[[simnr]]))$dane)
   user  system elapsed 
  0.088   0.004   0.093
```

While

```
? system.time(addcells(1))
user  system elapsed 
147.328   0.296 147.644
```

I would expect both commands to have comparable execution times (or at least the latter be max 10 x slower). I guess I am doing something very inefficient there, but what? The whole `cells` data structure is rather big, it takes around 1GB of memory.

I need to transpose data in this way, because later I do many descriptive statistics on the results (like computing means, sd, quantiles, and maybe histograms), so it is important, that the data for each cell is stored as a (single-dimensional) vector.

---

Here is profiling output:

```
> summaryRprof('/tmp/temp/rprof.out')
$by.self
                self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"[.data.frame"      71.98    47.20     129.52     84.93
"names"             11.98     7.86      11.98      7.86
"length"            10.84     7.11      10.84      7.11
"addcells"          10.66     6.99     151.52     99.36
".subset"           10.62     6.96      10.62      6.96
"["                  9.68     6.35     139.20     91.28
"match"              6.06     3.97      11.36      7.45
"sys.call"           4.68     3.07       4.68      3.07
"%in%"               4.50     2.95      15.86     10.40
"all"                4.28     2.81       4.28      2.81
"=="                 2.34     1.53       2.34      1.53
".subset2"           1.28     0.84       1.28      0.84
"is.na"              1.06     0.70       1.06      0.70
"nargs"              0.62     0.41       0.62      0.41
"gc"                 0.54     0.35       0.54      0.35
"!"                  0.42     0.28       0.42      0.28
"dim"                0.34     0.22       0.34      0.22
".Call"              0.12     0.08       0.12      0.08
"readRDS"            0.10     0.07       0.12      0.08
"cat"                0.10     0.07       0.10      0.07
"readLines"          0.04     0.03       0.04      0.03
"strsplit"           0.04     0.03       0.04      0.03
"addParaBreaks"      0.02     0.01       0.04      0.03
```

It looks that indexing the list structure takes a lot of time. But I can't make it array, because not all cells are numeric, and R doesn't easily support hash map...

Comment: You don't want to grow R objects at each iteration. If you do that R has to create an object in memory with the required space, copy everything across + the new data to the new object and get rid of the old memory. This entails a not insignificant effort, plus you are incurring potentially thousands of calls to many functions. Better to allocate storage in chunks. Say you don't know exactly how many rows/cols to add, add a 100, fill those in, keeping track of how many you've filled in with a counter. If you exceed those 100, allocate another 100 & repeat. When finished, remove empty rows/cols.

Comment: Adjust n = 100 to the size of the problem, using larger n for larger problems to avoid copying many times if you fill up the 100 new spaces too quickly.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I know this. That's why I pre-filled each cell. See the lines before the `addcells` function definition.

Comment: Sorry, I missed exactly what it was doing. OK, so the problem is the other thing I referred the; function calls to `[` and related methods. You seem to be filling cell by cell, looping over the rows and cols. Instead, replace entire rows or columns; find the indices of the non-`NA` elements in say each row and replace them all in a single call. Switch to doing this column-wise if the number of columns exceeds the number of rows.

Comment: Perhaps something like: `if (ind <- !is.na(simdata[j, ])) {
        cells[[j]][[ind]][simnr] <- simdata[j, ][ind]
}` and remove the inner `i` loop. Not tested there isn't a reproducible example.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Good point. BTW, there is a lot NAs in each data.frame, so it should give it a kick. I'll do it, but I feel that it would boost stuff max 10 times, when I expect to speed it up by the factor of thousands. After all it is just a simple transposition in memory; Mathematica handles such stuff in mere seconds.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Maybe I'll create a separate data structure for each type of the cell - and because of the uniform type, it can be an array. This way maybe I'll have that orders of magnitudes I am looking for...

Comment: If you can add an example, even if it is just a small one, we can try options. without seeing your data, why not just use `t()` on the whole thing, or just the numeric parts, as you don't need the non-numerics for the summary stats. What you are doing seems very non-R-ish so I'm not surprised this is slow. But it is hard to see what you are doing etc without a concrete example to play with.

Comment: @GavinSimpson If it is not R-ish, then how do people in R world analyse data about cases, when each case lives in a separate file?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Now I think that the idea with `if (ind <- !is.na(simdata[j, ])) { cells[[j]][[ind]][simnr] <- simdata[j, ][ind] }` shouldn't help much, because I **do** check for emptiness of cells in my file, and if it is NA I don't touch the `cells` structure anyway. And what you propose would introduce filtering, which is done by copying parts of the data. I don't see how it could provide any substantial benefits.

Comment: I did say it wasn't tested. Perhaps I have the logic backwards, but notice I dropped the index `i`, so I do all rows in column `j` (if `i` indexed the rows) in a single call, your way uses `i` calls per index `j`. As most of your time is in the `[.data.frame` method, this would cut out a lot of that with little change to the rest of your code. Then you don't need the inner loop.

Comment: As for not R-ish; I don't think I've ever written a double loop, except when I was directly coding up an algorithm i was going to write in C as a unit test. As I said, supply a small example so I don't have to understand all your code from scratch, then we can talk ;-)

Comment: @GavinSimpson Of course. I'm working at it.